# Custom Op: Reading/Writing to temporary GPU data

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I am writing a custom Tensorflow op. I need to send a custom data structure (constructed on the CPU) to the GPU to use in a CUDA kernel. However, it is my understanding that with Tensorflow managing the memory, only Tensors can be dynamically allocated, correct? If so:

a) How can I allocate a temporary tensor on the CPU to which I can write data from my custom data structure?

b) How can I memcpy this tensor to the GPU to be used with a CUDA kernel?

I see `allocate_temp` using `AllocatorAttributes` but the documentation is non-existent.

Basically I need the Caffe equivalent of `mutable_cpu_data` and `mutable_gpu_data`.

Comment: did you see this: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu

Comment: @xaxxon That isn't really relevant to a new op